# Deploy REST API as clusterIP and web app as NodePort

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

My REST API is deployed a clusterIP.
Web app consuming REST API is deployed as NodePort.
Both are on the same cluster.
When I run my web app the connection to the REST API (ClusterIP) fails.

Comment: Please share the output of `kubectl get service`. Also, yaml files for both pods. Also, the url you are using to connect from webapp to api.

Answer (score 1):

ClusterIP is a virtual IP so it will not be resolved from outside your cluster. Your web app will be used in browser so it will need a public URL for the restapi. You can create restapi also a node port service or you can add ingress service in your cluster and then use routing based on the hostpath.

Comment: Hi Aman, So is there any way to achieve :- Deploy and expose  rest api internally and UI externally using services on GKE?

Comment: just try adding ingress service it will solve your problem. You only need to expose the ingress service and rest you can handle from there. Keeping API internal will be a very rare case and you will have to do lot of adjustments for it.  
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/